# Fixing the top bar SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

The ribbonbar and suitebar which makes the top bar in SharePoint 2013 have a fixed like position on the site. When the user scrolls, the top bar follows.

I want this bar to stay at the top and NOT have this fixed like position.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

#topbar {overflow : hidden;position:fixed; top :0px; left:0px; }

Comment: You should add more commentary so that others coming across your answer can understand it more readily.

Answer (score 0):

Moving both the ribbonbar and the suitebar to the s4-workspace in the master file solved this issue